# My page goes out on mobile but not on desktop

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is my first post. When I view this on desktop it's fine, but when I access it on mobile and just pan it to the left, I see this. I tried positioning my elements on relative, don't know if that is what's causing this to go off screen on mobile. If you guys could explain this that would be awesome.

Comment: Can you please post both your HTML and CSS? We can't say what is wrong with your code unless we can see it :)

Comment: Yes this question would benefit greatly by having a [Minimal, Complete & Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What is actually being off screen? The logo to the left?